# Verifying the values of URL in Junit?

Tags: java, json, junit

I do have to write a unit test case for a method which returns a URL,
I've to verify all the values of the parameters in the URL, is there any API or better way to work around this..

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Java Method:

```
 class Sample{
      public String returnURL(){
          return "http://localhost:9080/sample?a=12-a&b=param2&c=param3&d=param_4&e=param5"
        }
}
```

Junit:

```
@Test
public void returnURLTest(){
  String url = new Sample().returnURL()
  // Parse the url 
  assert url['a'] == "param1"
 assert url['b'] == "param2"
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Post some code and someone might be able to help more. See [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Post the relevant code; your test code. Or at least post your conditions your testing

Answer (score 5):

If you use AssertJ, you can create the URI (or URL) object and use the assertions on it, as shown in those examples: https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-examples/blob/master/assertions-examples/src/test/java/org/assertj/examples/UriAssertionsExamples.java

```
assertThat(new URI("http://www.helloworld.org/index.html?happy=very")).hasParameter("happy", "very");
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll just have to parse the URL and compare the individual pieces you pull out.

Something like:

```
int indexOfNextParameter = url.indexOf("=");
List<String> parameters = new ArrayList<>();

while(youAreParsingTheURL){
    int indexOfParameter = url.indexOf("=", indexOfNextParameter);
    String parameter = url.substring("=", indexOfParameter);
    parameters.add(parameter);
}
```

Then just go through that parameters List and validate each item.